# How to pass param alongside model param to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now I am passing a model(building_approval) params via form.

```
Processing by BuildingApprovalsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FdZWpexusIHZ/3p04Vg1Pn8YxCrp1I8v06j68lI/PoTFeKKGKrc5upcQdaK6UENl0CBINcymgUlylSC8AW2RfA==", "building_approval"=>{"urgency"=>"urgent", "title"=>"title1", "member_id"=>"-1", "deal_bu\
ilding_id"=>"1", "building_name"=>"social 309", "building_id"=>"1", "fixed_price"=>"25000000", "sell_price"=>"50000000", "lowest_sell_price"=>"20000000", "loan_amount"=>"5000000", "deposit"=>"5300000", "disc\
ount_amount"=>"-25000000", "contract_date"=>"2019/03/26", "commission_type"=>"rent_offset", "commission_amount"=>"50000", "management_type"=>"loan", "room_support"=>"joined", "building_rank"=>"1", "memo"=>"", "comment"=>"", "customer_i\
d"=>"6", "approvals_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"member_id"=>"1", "approval_status"=>"pending", "tag_id"=>"56", "id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"member_id"=>"20", "approval_status"=>"pending", "tag_id"=>"55", "id"=>"2"}}}, "commit"=>"save", "prospective\
_customer_id"=>"6", "id"=>"1"}
```

I would like to pass a parameter called "reapply" alongside the model param(build_approval), authenticity_token and utf8. What is the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: I think the way I have suggested is the best way to do it. It's the simplict way of acheiving the functionalit you want. Mark as answered if it's sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a hidden parameter that would be sent when the form is submitted but will remain hidden out of sight from the user.

Add this to your form

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:reapply, @value) %>
```

where value can be declared in your controller or directly in the hidden field tag if it's constant.

Comment: is there a way to not use hidden tag? like inserting the hash to the forms default value which are the model , utf8 and authenticitiy_token?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use a `hidden_field`? This is common practice. If not, you may have to merge the attribute in your controller action